# Removed the skirt of the siding now the subflooring is exposed. What should I do?

Tags: foundation, waterproofing, siding

The skirt boards for the siding were partially covered in soil and rotting so I removed them. Now it looks like I exposed the subflooring. How do I prevent them from rotting now that they are exposed? The first picture shows what I removed but on a different part of the house.

[image]

Comment: A better photo of the actual detail would be great.

Answer (score 2):

Without a better picture, it appears to be a 2X plate that is attached to the concrete and not subfloor. If it is a home built within the past 30 or 40 years or so, it may be pressure treated (PT) to resist rot. If it is not pressure treated, it is doing pretty good, for where it is.

To fix the issue it will only need a piece big enough to cover over the concrete by no more than an inch. I could be a piece of pressure treated 1X4 or something of that nature. If you go that route, it will need to be nailed or screwed with fasteners approved for contact with PT material. They are available anywhere hardware is sold. The box will be marked " compatible with ACQ" or PT or "copper azole" lumber.

Depending on the thickness of the added piece, or maybe not you will want to add a flashing, so falling weather cannot go between the gap  of the siding and the added piece.

[image: Flashing]

If you can get the nails out that are in the way, it will be easy to separate the siding just a fraction to get a space big enough the slide the flashing in first. Then add the 1X4 under the flashing, that is if 1X4 is tall enough to cover over the concrete the 1", it may take 1X6. The hope would be is that you can use a piece to cover the problem, without it going into the dirt again. Using PT or not, it is never a good idea to let any kind of siding go below grade.

Comment: Wow this is incredibly helpful. Thank you so much!!!